# Groovy Grails Displaying a list vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to display a list of items on a Groovy Server Page (GSP) vertically instead of horizontally. Currently, my list is displaying horizontally. It appears as follows:

**Example 1**

```
[ A ] [ B ] [ C ]
[ D ] [ E ] [ F ]
[ G ] [ H ] [ I ]
[ J ] [ K ] [ L ]
```

Instead of displaying this list horizontally, I would like my list to appear vertically, or in the following order:

**Example 2: What I'm hoping to accomplish**

```
[ A ] [ E ] [ I ]
[ B ] [ F ] [ J ]
[ C ] [ G ] [ K ]
[ D ] [ H ] [ L ]
```

To accomplish the display of the horizontal list (Example 1), I did the following:

In my Controller, I have a simple list being defined:

```
def test() {
  def list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']
  [items: list]
 }
```

And on my test.gsp page, I have the following:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <%
            def counter = 0

            for (i in items) {
            counter = counter+1

            println("<td>" + i + "</td>")

            if (counter == 3) {
                println("</tr><tr>")
                counter = 0
            }
        }
        %>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Does anyone know how I can make my list appear like Example 2?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
list.collate( 3 ).transpose().flatten()
```

Comment: Question, Tim: I put the above code in my controller before outputting the list, and I appear to be getting the same thing as in my "Example 1". Am I just being dense or is there something that I'm not doing right in order to get it to work like Example 2?

Comment: @meoww- `list = list.collate( 3 ).transpose().flatten()` should make list equal `[A, D, G, J, B, E, H, K, C, F, I, L]`

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
List list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']
int size = list.size()
int modVal = 3

[items: list.collate( (size / modVal).toInteger() ).transpose().flatten(), modVal: modVal]
```

In the view:

```
<tr>
  <g:each in="${items}" var="item" status="i">
    <g:if test="${i % modVal == 0 && i != 0}">
      </tr><tr>
    </g:if>
    <td>${item}</td>
  </g:each>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks James. I like this solution as well. I appreciate you posting it here. Cheers